Google does not let me log in because it detects that it is an automated software (selenium)
I'm trying to access Google with Selenium, but when I enter my email to log in, Google detects that it is an automated software and won't let me continue. Is there any way to solve this?In reality, I do not log in automatically but manually, introducing a pause of 120 seconds to give me time to log in manually. This is the relevant code:
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Configura la ubicación del geckodriver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");

    // Inicializa el WebDriver para Firefox
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    //options.setHeadless(false); // Desactiva el modo headless
    //options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    String ventanaPrincipalHandle = null;
    List<String> urlsRecopiladas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Navega a la página de Google
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        // Guarda el identificador de la ventana principal
        ventanaPrincipalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

        // Espera unos segundos para permitir que se abra el popup
        esperar(3);

        // Imprime el número de ventanas abiertas
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println("Número de ventanas abiertas: " + handles.size());

        // Manejar el popup si se abre
        if (handles.size() > 1) {
            manejarPopup(driver, ventanaPrincipalHandle);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se abrió ningún popup.");
        }

        // Regresar a la ventana principal
        driver.switchTo().window(ventanaPrincipalHandle);

        // Acepta automáticamente las cookies si el banner está presente
        aceptarCookies(driver);

        // Realiza una búsqueda para "moda infantil online" y espera unos segundos para que los resultados se carguen inicialmente
        realizarBusqueda(driver, "moda infantil online");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Realiza seis scrolls hacia abajo
        realizarScrolls(driver, 6);

        // Recopila URLs de todas las páginas de resultados
        recopilarURLs(driver, urlsRecopiladas);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Cierra el navegador al final
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    // Imprime todas las URLs recopiladas al final con sus posiciones
    System.out.println("Todas las URLs recopiladas con sus posiciones:");
    for (int i = 0; i < urlsRecopiladas.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Posición " + (i + 1) + ": " + urlsRecopiladas.get(i));
    }
}


you can try creating a new profile manually, logging that in, closing the browser, and then setting Selenium to use that profile when initializing the webdriver.  Certain Google-owned sites would still detect you though.

Can't you use an API to do whatever you are trying to do?

the solution from browsermator didn't worked, the same result.And regarding the Google API, the program is to access the Google ranking for a keyword and with the Google API I got some crazy results, they were nothing like those of a manual search.
